# Interpolate specific entries in DataFrame depending on groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I am having an issue where I have AIS data of several trips from Rotterdam to Hamburg. The route is split into 6 sectors, with the sector borders pre-defined for the route, and I need to know where and when a ship entered the next sector. I tried just using the last record within a sector, but the data's resolution isn't high enough for that. So I would like to interpolate the time and longitude based on the latitude of the sector border.

You can see the borders I decided on for this trip in the following image. The longitude of crossing the border is always exactly on the border line. What I need to determine is the latitude at which this line is crossed by a ship.

[image: Map of my borders]

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
       TripID  time  Latitude Longitude  SectorID
0      42       7    52.9     4.4        1
1      42       8    53.0     4.6        1
2      42       9    53.0     4.7        1
3      42      10    53.1     4.9        2
4       5       9    53.0     4.5        1
5       5      10    53.0     4.7        1
6       5      11    53.2     5.0        2
7       5      12    53.3     5.2        2
```

where the border between sectors 1 and 2 is pre-defined at longitude 4.8, so I would like to interpolate both the latitude and time at longitude 4.8 for each trip and sector border. I'm guessing a good solution will involve something like `df.groupby(['TripID', 'SectorID'])`.

I tried adding an entry for each trip and sector that only has the Latitude of the sector's border in it and then using `interpolate`, but adding the entries takes about an hour for me and interpolating the missing values crashes right away.

The result I'm looking for should look like this:

```
       TripID  time  Latitude Longitude  SectorID
0      42       7    52.9     4.4        1
1      42       8    53.0     4.6        1
2      42       9    53.0     4.7        1
8      42     9.5   53.05     4.8        1
3      42      10    53.1     4.9        2
4       5       9    53.0     4.5        1
5       5      10    53.0     4.7        1
9       5    10.3   53.06     4.8        1
6       5      11    53.2     5.0        2
7       5      12    53.3     5.2        2
```

I would also be happy about and able to work with a result that looks like this:

```
 TripID  SectorID  leave_lat  leave_lon  leave_time
 42      1         53.05      4.8        9.5
 5       1         53.06      4.8        10.3
```

Please ask, if my description of the problem isn't quite clear.

Comment: The sector borders are pre-defined and not dependent on the data. The one I used as an example in the question is at longitude 4.8. Therefore, to get the position where the ship leaves the sector, I need to know what is the latitude, when the longitude is 4.8 (i.e. on the sector border). Does that make it clearer?

Comment: The different border values for latitude are on purpose. The border is basically a line at a longitude of 4.8. Different ships might cross this border a different latitudes. Those latitudes are what I would like to compute.

Comment: I added an image to clear things up a bit. Basically, I simply decided there should be a border at longitude 4.8 and I would like to know what latitude this border will be crossed at by a ship. However, I only know the latitudes at longitudes 4.7 and 4.9. I therefore need to interpolate the latitude for 4.8. Am I making sense? I'm sorry it's hard to understand. I'm not quite sure what isn't clear to you.

Comment: No, not difficult. Just ambiguous. So you assume linearity of movement between the known points, you define the longitude of your sectors (is this a given list? if so, how is it provided?) and you want to calculate the latitude of the ship movement under these assumptions. Does this summarize your problem correctly?

Comment: Yes, exactly! The list of borders is just something I came up with. It doesn't depend on the data.

Comment: Please include then in the question, how the sector longitudes are provided (list, pandas series, whatever).

Comment: They aren't exactly provided in anything. So far (e.g. for adding the sector IDs) I just put them in by hand like this: `df.loc[(df['Longitude'] > 4.8) & (df['Longitude'] <= 6.0), 'SectorID'] = '2'`. So I'm happy to provide them in any form that is practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the usual pandas crew hasn't spotted this nice question, I give you a solution with some caveats. Here is the sample input, I used:

```
TripID  time  Latitude Longitude  
42       7    52.9     4.4        
42       8    53.0     4.6        
42       9    53.0     4.7 * missing value
42      10    53.1     4.9 
42      11    53.2     4.9         
42      12    53.3     5.3 * missing value
42      15    53.7     5.6    
5        9    53.0     4.5        
5       10    53.0     4.7  * missing value
5       11    53.2     5.0       
5       12    53.4     5.2        
5       14    53.6     5.3  * missing value
5       17    53.4     5.5        
5       18    53.3     5.7  
34      19    53.0     4.5  
34      20    53.0     4.7          
34      24    53.9     4.8  ** value already exists
34      25    53.8     4.9        
34      27    53.8     5.3        
34      28    53.8     5.3  * missing value
34      31    53.7     5.6        
34      32    53.6     5.7
```

This code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#import data
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", delim_whitespace=True)

#set floating point output precision to prevent excessively long columns
pd.set_option("display.precision", 2)
#remember original column order
cols = df.columns
#define the sector borders
sectors = [4.8, 5.4]

#create all combinations of sector borders and TripIDs
dfborders = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.TripID.unique(), sectors], names = ["TripID", "Longitude"])).reset_index()
#delete those combinations of TripID and Longitude that already exist in the original dataframe
dfborders = pd.merge(df, dfborders, on = ["TripID", "Longitude"], how = "right")
dfborders = dfborders[dfborders.isnull().any(axis = 1)]
#insert missing data points
df = pd.concat([df, dfborders])
#and sort dataframe to insert the missing data points in the right position
df = df[cols].groupby("TripID", sort = False).apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, ["Longitude", "time", "Latitude"])

#temporarily set longitude as index for value-based interpolation
df.set_index(["Longitude"], inplace = True, drop = False)
#interpolate group-wise
df = df.groupby("TripID", sort = False).apply(lambda g: g.interpolate(method = "index"))
#create sector ID column assuming that longitude is between -180 and +180
df["SectorID"] = np.digitize(df["Longitude"], bins = [-180] + sectors + [180])
#and reset index
df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
print(df)
```

produces the following output:

```
    TripID   time  Latitude  Longitude  SectorID
0       42   7.00     52.90        4.4         1
1       42   8.00     53.00        4.6         1
2       42   9.00     53.00        4.7         1
3       42   9.50     53.05        4.8         2 * interpolated data point
4       42  10.00     53.10        4.9         2
5       42  11.00     53.20        4.9         2
6       42  12.00     53.30        5.3         2
7       42  13.00     53.43        5.4         3 * interpolated data point
8       42  15.00     53.70        5.6         3
9        5   9.00     53.00        4.5         1
10       5  10.00     53.00        4.7         1
11       5  10.33     53.07        4.8         2 * interpolated data point
12       5  11.00     53.20        5.0         2
13       5  12.00     53.40        5.2         2
14       5  14.00     53.60        5.3         2
15       5  15.50     53.50        5.4         3 * interpolated data point
16       5  17.00     53.40        5.5         3
17       5  18.00     53.30        5.7         3
18      34  19.00     53.00        4.5         1
19      34  20.00     53.00        4.7         1
20      34  24.00     53.90        4.8         2
21      34  25.00     53.80        4.9         2
22      34  27.00     53.80        5.3         2
23      34  28.00     53.80        5.3         2
24      34  29.00     53.77        5.4         3 * interpolated data point
25      34  31.00     53.70        5.6         3
26      34  32.00     53.60        5.7         3
```

Now to the caveats. I do not know, how to add the missing rows inplace. I will ask a question, how to do this. If I get an answer, I will update mine here. Until then, the side effect is that the table is sorted within each `TripID` for `Longitude` and the assumption is that `Longitude` does not decrease, which in reality might not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue in a different way. Because this solved the problem for me, but isn't the exact solution I asked for, I will accept Mr. T's answer. I am posting this for the sake of completeness anyway, so here is my solution:

Starting with the DataFrame `df` from my question

```
        TripID  time  Latitude Longitude  SectorID
0      42       7    52.9     4.4        1
1      42       8    53.0     4.6        1
2      42       9    53.0     4.7        1
3      42      10    53.1     4.9        2
4       5       9    53.0     4.5        1
5       5      10    53.0     4.7        1
6       5      11    53.2     5.0        2
7       5      12    53.3     5.2        2
```

I used this code

```
df = df.sort_values('time')

df['next_lat'] = df.groupby('TripID')['Latitude'].shift(-1)
df['next_lon'] = df('TripID')['Longitude'].shift(-1)
df['next_time'] = df('TripID')['time'].shift(-1)
df['next_sector_id'] = df('TripID')['sector'].shift(-1)
df = df.sort_values(['TripID', 'time'])
df['next_trip_id'] = df['TripID'].shift(-1)

lasts = df[df['SectorID'] != df['next_sector_id']]

lasts.loc[lasts['SectorID'] == '1', 'sector_leave_lon'] = 4.8

lasts.loc[lasts['sector'] == '2', 'sector_leave_lat'] = lasts.loc[lasts['sector'] == '2', 'Latitude'] + ((lasts.loc[lasts['sector'] == '2', 'sector_leave_lon'] - lasts.loc[lasts['sector'] == '2', 'Longitude']) / (lasts.loc[lasts['sector'] == '2', 'next_lon'] - lasts.loc[lasts['sector'] == '2', 'Longitude'])) * (lasts.loc[lasts['sector'] == '2', 'next_lon'] - lasts.loc[lasts['sector'] == '2', 'Longitude'])

lasts.loc[lasts['sector'] == '2', 'sector_leave_time'] = lasts.loc[lasts['sector'] == '2', 'time'] + ((lasts.loc[lasts['sector'] == '2', 'sector_leave_lon'] - lasts.loc[lasts['sector'] == '2', 'Longitude']) / (lasts.loc[lasts['sector'] == '2', 'next_lon'] - lasts.loc[lasts['sector'] == '2', 'Longitude'])) * (lasts.loc[lasts['sector'] == '2', 'next_time'] - lasts.loc[lasts['sector'] == '2', 'time'])

df['sector_leave_lat'] = lasts['sector_leave_lat']
df['sector_leave_time'] = lasts['sector_leave_time']

df['sector_leave_lat'] = df(['TripID', 'sector'])['sector_leave_lat'].transform('last')
df['sector_leave_time'] = df(['TripID', 'sector'])['sector_leave_time'].transform('last')

df = df.drop(['next_lat', 'next_lon', 'next_time', 'next_sector_id', 'next_trip_id'], axis = 1)
```

which gives a result likes this

```
        TripID  time  Latitude Longitude  SectorID  sector_leave_lat  sector_leave_time
0      42       7    52.9     4.4        1          53.05              9.5
1      42       8    53.0     4.6        1          53.05              9.5
2      42       9    53.0     4.7        1          53.05              9.5
3      42      10    53.1     4.9        2          NaN               NaN
4       5       9    53.0     4.5        1          53.06             10.3
5       5      10    53.0     4.7        1          53.06             10.3
6       5      11    53.2     5.0        2          NaN               NaN
7       5      12    53.3     5.2        2          NaN               NaN
```

I hope this helps those to who the actual solution doesn't cut it.